# How to send default nextjs 404 not found error page from express?

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

I'm trying to a default nextjs error page from my express endpoints, when an exception happens in my endpoint functions. What I'm doing right now is:

```js
try {
  //...
} catch(e) {
  res.status(404).send('Not Found !!!');
}
```

How can I send a default nextjs 404 page instead of doing above?

Comment: You can do a `res.redirect('http://example.com/404')`. Some doc: https://expressjs.com/fr/api.html#res.redirect

Comment: No, in NextJS this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot close the response before rendering the app in next, so you have to use `app.render` with the `res` modified

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
try {
  //...
} catch(e) {
 res.writeHead(301, { Location :"/"});
 res.end();

}
```